# Supergirl (CW): Searching episode with POV view of Kryptons destruction

Tags: dc, arrowverse, episode-identification, supergirl-2015

I've watched a Supergirl episode on TV some time ago and there was a scene where Supergirl remembers flying away from her home planet Krypton (destruction). It was shot from her point of view (POV), looking up-and sidewards. Can anyone tell me, which episode this is from? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure this happened in season two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It an episode from season 3; specifically ***Season 3 Episode 2: Triggers***. When Gayle Marsh a.k.a Psi psychically attacks Supergirl the second time, Kara experiences a sort of *déjà vu*/vision where she sees her mother and the destruction of Krypton first-hand again.

***PS***: *To be precise its somewhere around the 15th minute mark of this episode.*